# Keyboard settings crashes at post-reset setup, can't access phone

Tags: root-access, keyboard, 5.1-lollipop, bootloader, crashes

I rooted my device and everything went fine (Kingo Root automatic app). Some time after making my first steps into the rooted device, I tried a "Reboot menu" widget, a window with options popped out and I clicked on "Bootloader" and the phone restarted (I have no custom recovery) and went to pin input then home screen and everything felt fine until I tried to search something and the keyboard didn't appear. Went in Settings, then Language and Input, and the app crashed leaving a "Settings app has stopped." message. I tried another keyboard to substitute but nothing happened (still could not access keyboard settings).
I saw after that on a forum that a guy fixed all of this by factory resetting his phone so I tried it, and now I'm supposed to be at the setup page (like the first time you boot) and as always first thing to set is Input, and as the whole keyboard settings is bugged, I constantly get a warning "Settings has stopped working" and click on OK and it reappears.
Pretty much can't access anything on my phone.
Is there a way to prevent Settings app from further crashing from within a PC connected to the phone?
Or completely resetting the phone? Data is of no concern, I just want my keyboard working again.

P.S. Have I done something to the android keyboard? (maybe deleted it by bootloading? unaware though..) Maybe I have to completely wipe and reinstall settings app? Being a newbie, how can I do all this?
Thanks in advance, any help appreciated

Comment: Please provide more details like which phone, android  version etc being relevant information. Coming to your present situation, please read up on how to remove root and restore to stock completely. Root is a powerful thing and doing anything after rooting means you should be aware of the consequences an of need be how to recover from it. This is not to discourage you from rooting but to encourage you to understand what you are doing before acting

Comment: I do not understand what could be causing the Settings app to crash (given the events here) but if after the factory reset the app is still crashing then consider flashing the ROM from scratch.

Comment: @beeshyams LG L90 D405, Android Lollipop v5.1.1, Stock LG Keyboard 
So I might have to flash the ROM and reroot it? Is there a way to install a keyboard apk from the PC (I have access to both Win and Linux) directly on the device in case my whole keyboard has been corrupted?

Comment: Theoretically, I am guessing yes, not being familiar with LG. But would recommend roll back to stock as also recommend by fire lord

Comment: I flashed it back and it's working perfectly, safe backup and all. Thanks!